# Get value of child from the value of another child with the same parent in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML document:

```
<response>
    <message>
        <badgeid>13</badgeid>
        <level>4672</level>
        <completion_time>1518626787</completion_time>
        <xp>4922</xp>
        <scarcity>9717</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>25</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1480166791</completion_time>
        <xp>25</xp>
        <scarcity>3761041</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>21</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1467581153</completion_time>
        <xp>100</xp>
        <scarcity>16650345</scarcity>
    </message>
</response>
```

I am trying to create a program using PHP that returns the "scarcity" of a certain "badgeid" (that is always unique).

So my question is: How do I get the value of `<scarcity></scarcity>` when the only input I receive from the user is a unique `badgeid`? In general words: How do I get the value of a child from the value of another child with the same parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://php.net/simplexml_load_string) for an XML string, or [`simplexml_load_file()`](https://php.net/simplexml_load_file) if it is a XML file. Then you could iterate over `$xml->message` and check if `$message->badgeid` is the item you want :

```
$xmlstr = '<response>
    <message>
        <badgeid>13</badgeid>
        <level>4672</level>
        <completion_time>1518626787</completion_time>
        <xp>4922</xp>
        <scarcity>9717</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>25</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1480166791</completion_time>
        <xp>25</xp>
        <scarcity>3761041</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>21</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1467581153</completion_time>
        <xp>100</xp>
        <scarcity>16650345</scarcity>
    </message>
</response>';

$badgeid = 21 ; // The value you want to search
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$scarcity = null ;
foreach ($xml->message as $message) {
    if ((string)$message->badgeid == $badgeid) {
        $scarcity = (string)$message->scarcity ;
        break ;
    }
}

// use $scarcity if set.
if (isset($scarcity)) {
    // do stuff
    echo $scarcity ; // 16650345
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an xpath expression and use the `$badgeid` as a parameter:

```
$expression = "/response/message[./badgeid='$badgeid']";
```

Then you could for example use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$data = <<<DATA
<response>
    <message>
        <badgeid>13</badgeid>
        <level>4672</level>
        <completion_time>1518626787</completion_time>
        <xp>4922</xp>
        <scarcity>9717</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>25</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1480166791</completion_time>
        <xp>25</xp>
        <scarcity>3761041</scarcity>
    </message>
    <message>
        <badgeid>21</badgeid>
        <level>1</level>
        <completion_time>1467581153</completion_time>
        <xp>100</xp>
        <scarcity>16650345</scarcity>
    </message>
</response>
DATA;

$badgeid = 25;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$expression = "/response/message[./badgeid='$badgeid']";
$items = $xml->xpath($expression);

if (count($items) === 1) {
    echo $items[0]->scarcity;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$res = $xpath->query($expression);

if ($res->length === 1) {
    echo $res->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("scarcity")->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/l27o0)

Comment: Interesting answer. I always forget xpath :) Well done! My answer is no longer useful I think ;)

Comment: It was! Although this answer is definitely very useful as well, your answer helped me figure it out and was simpler in my case.